# Size of SQL disk storage space growing 32GB a day

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Since April 1st, the size of my DB storage space grows by 32GB a day. It's very unusual, and based on the 500GB disk, this will not last for much longer.

Why is the DB growing by 32GB a day?

For context, I've allocated a 500GB disk; binary logs are enabled; automated backups are enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested further. The reason for the DB growing so dramatically every night is due to the binary logs. Every night Magento indexes run, and produce 32GB of binary logging data. Not all Magento stores will be the same, but large Magento stores beware.

The solution, temporarily at least, is to disable binary logging. Have a look at the image to see the reclaimed disk space after disabling the option.

This will make it a challenge when setting up read/failover replicas. It would be nice if the MySQL instance is configured to purge/prune binary logs after a set amount of time has passed, or at least once operations have been copied to slave instances. Maybe it does, but I haven't investigated. Given current time constraints, I was not going to wait until the purge/prune happened, if it even would.

[image]

Comment: Note that binary logs are kept for 7 days, so disk usage should stabilize after a week.

Comment: @rvs Where did you read that? I can't find this in the docs anywhere.

Comment: Good point, I can't find relevant docs. There's something here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#backups_cost

I know this because I work on CloudSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be your DB log that is growing at a rapid pace?

I have had this issue in the past and ended up creating a job for the SQL agent that runs once a week and purges the log.

Comment: The one thing I'm thinking could be responsible for this are the binary logs. It was from around that date that I started running a cron every night to run Magento indexes, which take considerable time, and makes about 1.7M updates/writes. I still have some testing, so I'm not sure if this is even possible.